# How can I cut off results in a full-text (boolean mode) search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I'm using a boolean mode full-text search:

```
SELECT *, match(Tournament.Name) against ('query' in boolean mode) as score FROM `tournaments` AS `Tournament` WHERE 1 =1 ORDER BY `score` desc LIMIT 20
```

What I wanted to do was to change the `where` clause to contain something like `score > 0.5`, but this threw an error about score being an unknown column.

Is there a way around this? Or is my method flawed?

---

**EDIT:** For example, say I search for "cheese", I get the following results:

- Cheese is great
- I love cheese
- Cheese ftw
- Cake is nice too
- Anyone for a cuppa?

The query has successfully sorted the matches to the top (they have good scores), but the others (with scores of 0) are left in the result set. I want to filter out these low scoring results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick James [answered](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,436927,437075) this over at the MySQL dev forums.

He wrote:

> "score" is derived, so it cannot be in WHERE. Use HAVING instead of
>   WHERE in this situation

```
SELECT ... AS score
FROM ...
WHERE ...
HAVING score > 0.5
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you have a look at the basic mysql [functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), to extract substrings from strings and convert them into a number. You can use them in you were clause and compare the result to 0.5

Comment: I'm not sure how this would help. To be clear, the search is already working, I just want to stop it returning the non-matches.

Comment: @tom, Ok I haven't understood your question then: if the search is working why do you need to stop returning then non-matches ? non returning things is what you expect from a search isn't it ?